# Why to_numeric() function in pandas does not convert float64 to int64?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH9ob.png)

Hi I am trying to convert a column in my data frame which is float64 type to int64 but for some reason it does not work.
I tried to do it in my main DF which I created from excel but that didn't work either.

Comment: Isn't `float64` a numeric type already? Maybe you want to convert to an `integer` dtype?

Comment: Also, should not you look at `DF.info()` instead?

Comment: Yes, i want to convert it to integer. Also i am sorry about DF info but even that says float64 as datatype

Comment: @nimbous i have updated the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

check if nan are present. Is not possible to convert a np.nan into int

```
df["col"] = df["col"].astype(float)
```

Comment: there are no nan values present. I have updated the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Ski_DF['fastEight'] = Ski_DF['fastEight'].astype(int)
```

or alternatively:

```
Ski_DF['fastEight'] = pd.to_numeric(Ski_DF['fastEight'], downcast='integer', errors='ignore')
```